Android Studio "Projects"
AS I'm learning Kotlin and Android development I have created a number of working Android Studio projects focused on certain aspects. ie. barcode scanning or printing and a number of others. One goal might be to combine the learned code of several of these features into one larger project. Today I went back and reopened one such working project and find that it riddled with code errors of some kind. The MainActivity,kt file seems intact but have I lost Gradle info or what happened. What am I missing? Did I not save these projects correctly? Hmmm do I need to "Save all" when I close down a project. Duh?

I've seen two different reasons for a newly opened project give linting errors when it had no errors when opened before.

For some reason the resources have not been built, this results in lots of red highlight for resource string (usually the R is in red). Select "Build" -> "Make Project" usually fixes this.

The project has not indexed all the libraries yet as shown by the project bar in the bottom right of Android Studio . The solution is to just wait for it to finish indexing/building.



In addition, ensure that your internet works, or these builds can mess with you. Happy  Coding.
